# How do I make a collection of points on a line all individually move according to their individual axes?

Tags: edit-mode

When I'm moving vertices in edit mode, I want to expand an entire collection of points about their local z axis so they all move outward perpendicularly. With lots of intricate curves, simply scaling from some median point isn't accurate enough, and it's also inefficient to manually select each vertex and move each one according to its local z.

But, when I select an entire segment composed of connected vertices, it doesn't move those vertices by their individual origins when I set the mode to individual origins, it treats the curve as just one object, so how do I overcome this?

Comment: Are you editing a Curve, or a Mesh?

Comment: Mesh...........